# Apply one style to Word 2013 .docx assembled from several sources

Tags: microsoft-word, themes

I never use Word (I have Word 2013 on Win 8.1 Pro) and I can't figure out how to apply one consistent theme so that it applies the same font/spacing/etc. to the whole document.

I use LaTeX, but my co-authors prefer Word (I can't blame them, the track changes features look pretty great), so I've assembled parts from emails, Word, and LaTeX text files and pasted them into one file. But when I apply a theme under the Design tab, it seems to only update the headings. The font, font size, and spacing are unchanged.

Is there a way to paint one style/theme on a Word .docx assembled piecemeal from several sources?

Is there a good reference for Word users coming from LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word is very self explanatory and it is WYSIWYG unlike latex. I would suggest selecting all parts of a style (done by right clicking on a style in the design tab) and editing the properties of the text in the font and paragraph dialog boxes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure it's self explanatory. When I highlight the entire document and apply a theme, it does not apply the font, size, and spacing to the document. What is the point of this feature? Is there a way to actually apply one theme to the whole document rather than separately adjusting all the settings?

Comment: I imagine the point is so that it doesn't apply a style to an entire document when you want it on just this patch of text. I may have misunderstood you, if you wanted to apply a single text style to an entire document, I suggest selecting everything in the document with Ctrl+a and then applying the style.

Comment: "I suggest selecting everything in the document with Ctrl+a and then applying the style." That's what doesn't work. Maybe there's no easy way. Odd, because this seems like a fairly common use case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The best that I can piece together is that "style sets", fonts, and paragraph spacing are *independent* (along with "themes", colors, and effects). To get the desired effect (i.e., applying one consistent formatting to an entire document) you must change all of these. So `CTRL-a`, then adjust each of these manually. FWIW, I also cleared all formatting first. That is `CTRL-a`, right-click, select "Style", then "Clear Formatting". Thanks for the help. I guess this is as good as it gets, but a little frustrating that "styles" and "themes" are not all-inclusive.